# Is there an overview of element selection methods in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if there's a good overview with examples that shows all the different ways of accessing html elements with jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

The jQuery JavaScript library [section on selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

[This tool](http://codylindley.com/jqueryselectors/) is kind of neat.  Also [Learning jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/) is a great blog on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

dzone.com offers a great reference card (works offline - when printed)

Download
 [jQuery selector Reference card](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/jquery-selectors)